# What does "Yippee-ki-yay" even mean?

Tags: dialogue, die-hard

In the Die Hard series, John Mcclane often uses this phrase before delivering the punch-blow that **exterminates** whatever he's aiming to blow up. But Mcclane ain't from Texas or anywhere in the Mid-West, but from New York. Sure the word *after* this phase (MoFo) is too common for a New York detective, but what is "Yippee-ki-yay" ?

Comment: OH right, yeah !